# How to search for \emph{.} and replace it with . in Vim?

Tags: vim

I want to search for e.g.

```
\emph{word}
```

and replace it

with

```
word
```

So, I want to delete the surrounding \emph{}.

How can I do this using Vim?

Answer (score 5):

Try `:%s/\\emph{\([^}]*\)}/\1/g`

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here: [Vim searches](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace)

You probably want something like `:%s/\\emph{\([^}]+\)}/\1/g`

Comment: Edited as I missed an escape!

Answer (score 1):

If `word` can contain nested subgroups (like in `\emph{Do {\bf something} now}` which is valid) you will have to use (in normal mode)

```
qaqqa/\\emph<CR>dt{ds{@aq@a
```

This assumes that you have [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) installed.